# Debugging Async Guzzle request/responses (Windows)

Tags: symfony, curl, asynchronous, guzzle

I'm using Guzzle 3.8.1 via Misd GuzzleBundle in Symfony (2.4.*). Both in my development and testing environments (both have the api endpoints on the same server), I am able to fire Async post requests with success.

In my production environment my endpoint is on the same server but accessed via a separate subdomain using apache vhosts. I am using Basic Authentication, at the moment it is via http (eventually https). However my Async requests are returning 200 status codes but I'm not getting POST data stored on my remote server for these requests.

```
$this->client->addSubscriber(new AsyncPlugin());

$request = $this->client->post(
    'statements',
    array(
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'X-Experience-API-Version' => '1.0.1'
    ),
    json_encode($statement)
)->setAuth($this->authuname,$this->authpass);

$response = $request->send();
```

However if I remove the `$this->client->addSubscriber(new AsyncPlugin());` and fire the same post request synchronously then my POST data is stored on the remote server.

I am using the logging functionality in the misd guzzle bundle. For the asynch request log I can see the json data in the request, as it doesn't wait for the response all I get is:

`<<<<<<< HTTP/1.1 200 OK X-Guzzle-Async: Did not wait for the response --------`

I have checked curl and it is enabled and same set up in dev than it is in production. The only issue is that async isn't working on the production server. I am using apache 2.4.6 on Windows Server 2008.

Has anyone else had similiar issues. Is there anyway to log the responses somewhere even though this is done asynchronously. I have logging set up in my vhosts, but as it's getting a 200 I'm not seeing anything there.

Hope someone can advise, let me know if you need any further information.

Kind regards,
Paul Pounder

Comment: Having said that, I have just read https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/579 so maybe I should just not bother using it.